# Need help adding a playAgain loop into my code

Tags: loops, while-loop, user-input, playback

This program suppose to get 2 numbers from the user. and direct it as high or low, the order shouldn't matter. It will then cause the computer to generate a random number and the user must input a number to see if it will match. My program will then display if the user number is too low or too high.

What I need help with is putting a playAgain loop inside this code. It should say"Would you like to play again? (Y/N)". It would then get the user string or char and will run the program again or end the program(depending on what the user enters).

I've been working and researching it for hours and can't seem to find a way(Maybe I'm dense lol). Sorry if I posted this question a 2nd time, I need to get this done by the end of today.

```
import java.util.*;

/*
Guessing Game Group Project.  This game will ask for two numbers to set the range,
*/

public class Guess1
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner S = new Scanner(System.in);                                                                                                                             //Introduction Statement to game
        System.out.println("This is a guessing game.  I will ask you for two numbers.");
        System.out.println("I will choose a random number between your two numbers for you " + "\n" + "to try and guess.  As you guess, I will give you hints.");

        System.out.print("Choose two numbers to bound your range: ");                                                                                                   //Scanner to store user's input for the range
        int u1 = S.nextInt();
        int u2 = S.nextInt();
        int guess;
        int count = 0; // = 0 new
        String playAgain;

        int high;
        int low;
        if(u1 < u2)
        {
            high = u2;
            low = u1;
        }
        else
        {
            high = u1;
            low = u2;
        }
        Random gen = new Random();
        int rand = gen.nextInt(high-low+1) + low;
        System.out.println("Now guess a number between " + low + " and " + high + ": ");
        guess = S.nextInt();
        while(guess != rand)
        {
            count++;
            if (guess > high || guess < low)
            {
                System.out.println("Out of range. Please follow the directions dumb-ass.");
            }
            else if(guess > rand)
            {
                high = guess;
                System.out.println("Too high!");
            }
            else
            {
                low = guess;
                System.out.println("Too low!");
            }

            System.out.print("Now guess a number between " + low + " and " + high + ": ");
            guess = S.nextInt();

            if(guess == rand)
            {
                System.out.println("You got it!");
            }
            else if(count == 10)
            {
                System.out.println("You lost! So Sorry.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a second loop around the body of your game that asks the continuation question. If the players says no you can exit. Look at the java doc for Scanner to see what it can read in.